# Create union type for keys of properties with specific shape

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, type-narrowing

I have this object structure `SomeParamList`, where the key is a string and the values may be undefined or a on object of arbitrary key value pairs.
I want to specify a union type of the object keys that only include the ones where the value has at least `{ password: string }` in it.

```
type SomeParamList = {
  FirstScreen: undefined,
  SecondScreen: {someParam: string}
  ThirdScreen: {password: string, name: string},
  FourthScreen: {password:string}
}

type KeysWithPass = ...
//   ^?  "ThirdScreen" | "FourthScreen"
```

EDIT:

What I have tried so far is this:

```
type Narrowed<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? T[K] : never;
};
```

It returns an object where all properties are `never` where the type does not extend. But when I try to do `keyof` of this, it just returns the original type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should can use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to filter out the correct properties inside a mapped type. Using `keyof` on the resulting type will return the string literal types you are looking for.

```
type Narrowed<T, U> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends U ? K : never]: any;
};

type KeysWithPass = Narrowed<SomeParamList, { password: string }>
// type KeysWithPass = "ThirdScreen" | "FourthScreen"
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgBQIYCdUIDIEsDOwUAvFAN4BQUUAYruoTAMboQQB2AXFAK7sAmEAGa52EfgBoqsCEzgDmrDtzL5EKDFm6F0ogOYBfaQBUAFvX6K2XcmFT58Adzjp+24LvZ6JUdlgjunoZS1DRwPOjAplbKtvZOLm46+kZGFKCQUAByGOhwjuIAPMY+AKoAfCRQANYQIHBC5NIA2gDSUKI1dQ1QxlD2vW0AulAQAB7AHPz4UKVQAPxQ7dxiAG4Q6EPcqOwgANwUBgfp4NCtdfgA6rhRaA5VOeh5BfyF8EhomDgEwD5kUHYHM5XIF9FADOUKAB6KFQDJnC7XW7xKoAIjMFhi7FRUAAPlBUWEIlEsaigA)

Comment: omg i was so close, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

So I had misunderstood the question. Here is the union, as requested:

```
type IfHasPassword<T> = T extends T & { password: string } ? T : never;
type KeysWithPass = IfHasPassword<SomeParamList[keyof SomeParamList]>
```

What checks for password is mainly this snippet: `T extends T & { password: string }`

As far as I'm aware, the helper type is necessary.

---

Original answer:

I think this is what you want:

```
type KeysWithPass<T extends { password: string }> = T;

function withPassword<T extends { password: string }>(param: T) {
    return param.password
}
```

If you want it to be part of the `SomeParamList` you have to further constrain the type, like so:

```
type KeysWithPass<T extends { password: string } & SomeParamList[keyof SomeParamList]> = T;
```

Comment: I want a union type of the objects keys, where the value extends {password:string}. This does not work...

Comment: I don't want to use a function or so. I just want the type.

Comment: Ohh sorry I misunderstood the question originally. I've updated the answer and I think that's what you want ^^

Comment: Wait I just noticed that you want the keys not the value types... I'll rework my answer and post it if I find something